# Start service when device boot completed

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

I am doing an application in which I want to call a number when that device boot completed. My code is like this:

```
 @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("**inside onRecevier");

        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent();
        serviceIntent.setAction("com.test.app.TestService");
        context.startService(serviceIntent); 

   }
```

First I created BroadcastReceiver. I registered this receiver in manifest file like this:

```
<receiver android:name="TestReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
             <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
             <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
        </intent-filter>    
    </receiver>
```

In a receiver I called the below service:

```
public class TestService extends Service{

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.out.println("**inside onCreate");
        super.onCreate();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Intent call = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL,Uri.parse("tel:+5555")); 
        startActivity(call);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.out.println("**inside onDestroy");
        super.onDestroy();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Destroyed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("**inside onStart");
        super.onStart(intent, startId);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

when I tried to boot a device after booting the application getting force close. How to do this in android??
Thanx in advance

Comment: Please post exception's description and stacktrace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the NEW_TASK flag before starting an activity from a service:

```
Intent call = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL,Uri.parse("tel:+5555"));
call.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(call);
```

[This](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startActivity%28android.content.Intent%29) explains:

> Note that if this method is being called from outside of an Activity
>   Context, then the Intent must include the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
>   launch flag. This is because, without being started from an existing
>   Activity, there is no existing task in which to place the new activity
>   and thus it needs to be placed in its own separate task.

Also, you must hold the permissions:

- [`RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED)
- [`CALL_PHONE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#CALL_PHONE)

And as Waqas mentioned, it would be better for you to start your service from your `onReceive` like:

```
 Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, TestService.class);
 context.startService(serviceIntent);
```

Make sure you've done all that I've stated, and if you continue to have an issue, then it would be helpful if you edit your question and paste the logcat from the force close.

Answer (score 0):

change your onReceive to this

```
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("**inside onRecevier");

        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, TestService.class);
        context.startService(serviceIntent); 

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a variety of reasons why you'd get a Force Close. The best way to tell which is to look at the log. It should tell you exactly what exception is being thrown, and give you a hint as to how to solve the problem.

Comment: This isn't really an answer and is more something that should be posted as a comment to the question.